# Error handling/checking in the kernel realm

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

What is the equivalent to `errno` in the kernel realm? More precisely, how do I check what error has happened for example when using a function like `kmalloc()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Linux kernel uses a couple of different methods for dealing with error conditions. Unlike C userspace programs, functions do not store their error code in a global variable, but return the value directly. You typically see that this is done as follows:

- Functions that return no value apart from an error code typically return `0` upon success and `-ESOMETHING` upon failure.
- Functions that may return a non-negative numerical value (e.g., an index, a file descriptor number or a length in bytes) are similar: 0 or higher indicates success and negative values indicate errors.
- Functions that return pointers may return a value in a special range to indicate an error. By calling `IS_ERR()` on the return value, you can check whether an error occurred. With `PTR_ERR()` you can extract the error code, which is again negated.

Unfortunately, the `kmalloc()` function uses none of these styles. It returns `NULL` upon failure without giving you a specific error code.

Comment: I'd add that `kmalloc()` can also return `ZERO_SIZE_PTR` in case when provided size is 0. So you should check your size explicitly before calling `kmalloc()` to avoid dealing with `ZERO_SIZE_PTR`. Also, consider using `PTR_ERR_OR_ZERO()` instead of stuff like `PTR_RET()` (which is deprecated now), `IS_ERR()` and `PTR_ERR()`.

Comment: Someone might be surprised to see non NULL code returned by malloc when size is 0! So, be carefull in the code. @SamProtsenko already told you the details.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a `errno` in the kernel realm. You can just **check the return of a kernel function** with an if statement for example for the `kmalloc()`:

```
struct dog *ptr;

ptr = kmalloc(sizeof(struct dog), GFP_KERNEL);
if (!ptr)
    /* handle error ... */
```

Where you handle your error you could then decide which would be the errno value in the user space just with:

```
return -ErrorName;
```

Linux kernel then interprets this negative value through the library errno.h. You can find the list of Errors to set the `errno` variable in:

```
include/asm-generic/errno.h
include/asm-generic/errno-base.h
```

Comment: thank you so much.. btw, why do we need to return a negative value of the error? (I've seen everyone does that on several examples online)

Comment: @LiorGolan this depends on the implementation of the syscall which uses (in most cases) the return value from the kernel to fill in the value of errno. We could say that almost all the syscall set the errno if the return value from the kernel is negative, there is not a specific reason it's a convection